# Is "@" a special character in regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I am working on an email filter and I have come across a list of regular expressions that are used to block all emails coming from senders that match a record in that list. While browsing through the list, I have discovered that *all* occurrences of the `@` character are escaped with a `\`.

Does the `@` mean anything special in regular expressions and needs to be escaped like so `\@`?

Comment: Not in most flavors of regex I know. It might be helpful if you add the language you're using, it may have ouy of the ordinary behavior / escape needs.

Comment: It could be a special character in Perl for example. So `@` is escaped to make sure Perl is not trying to evaluate the rest as an array name. Which language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *normally* not a special character, but it doesn't hurt to escape it which is probably why many people do it, they just want to be safe (or they think it's a special character).

Answer (score 1):

No, the @ is not special character in regex.

The the \ can be use in this meaning

Pattern:
\Q...\E

Def
Matches the characters between \Q and \E literally, suppressing the meaning of special characters.

Example:
\Q+-*/\E matches +-*/